# cookbook_name in recipe- TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have the following code in my recipe but it errors.

```
log "###" + cookbook_name + "::" + recipe_name + " " + Time.now.inspect + ": Starting execution phase"
puts "###" + cookbook_name + "::" + recipe_name + " " + Time.now.inspect + ": Starting compile phase"
```

The error is:

```
TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String
/test/chef/cookbooks/cookbook-server/recipes/setup_server.rb:10:in `+'
```

The issue seems to be with the `cookbook_name`, `recipe_name` etc.(the ones which are not hardcoded). Please help.

Comment: Anyone know what could be the issue here?

Answer (score 5):

When you're doing `+` action with the strings in Ruby, it doesn't convert other types to strings. If you want from Ruby to do that automatically, you need to do interpolation like:

```
puts "### #{cookbook_name} :: #{recipe_name} #{Time.now.inspect} : Starting compile phase"
```

If you want to use `+` you need to provide all variables as strings:

```
puts "###" + cookbook_name.to_s + "::" + recipe_name.to_s + " " + Time.now.inspect + ": Starting compile phase"
```

I suggest you to use first method.