# Does chef-solo support cookbook_name and recipe_name

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, chef-solo

I have the below & it errors because of cookbook_name and recipe_name.

log "###" + cookbook_name + "::" + recipe_name + " " + Time.now.inspect + ": Finished execution phase"

Comment: There is no need to create duplicate questions if there is not yet answer to first one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [cookbook\_name in recipe- TypeError: no implicit conversion of Symbol into String](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28842642/cookbook-name-in-recipe-typeerror-no-implicit-conversion-of-symbol-into-string)